# EF Core: Take() also limits results of include

Tags: entity-framework

I have following query:

```
 var query = this.DbContext.Products.AsNoTracking()
        .WhereIf(publishedFrom.HasValue, x => x.Erscheinen.Value >= publishedFrom)
        .WhereIf(publishedTo.HasValue, x => x.Erscheinen.Value < publishedTo)
        .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(publisherCode), x=> x.VerlagCode == publisherCode)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.GeplantesErscheinen)
        .Take(maxResultCount)
        .Include(x => x.SubjectAreas)
        .Include(x => x.ProductPrices)
        .Include(x => x.ProductOriginators);
     ;
```

The query should return the Product-Entity based on 3 where conditions and a order by. Related entities should be included. Afterwards only the First maxResultCount of the product query result should be returned. For the products ALL related entities should be loaded.

HOWEVER, Take() also has an impact on the query of the related entities. When I look into the sql server profiler I see followign query executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [a0].[ProductId], [a0].[SubjectAreaId], [t].[Id]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_3) [a].[Id], [a].[GeplantesErscheinen]
    FROM [AppProducts] AS [a]
    WHERE ((((@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ([a].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit))) AND ([a].[Erscheinen] >= @__publishedFrom_0)) AND ([a].[Erscheinen] < @__publishedTo_1)) AND ([a].[VerlagCode] = @__publisherCode_2)
    ORDER BY [a].[GeplantesErscheinen] DESC
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [AppProductSubjectArea] AS [a0] ON [t].[Id] = [a0].[ProductId]
ORDER BY [t].[GeplantesErscheinen] DESC, [t].[Id]',N'@__p_3 int,@__ef_filter__p_0 bit,@__publishedFrom_0 datetime2(7),@__publishedTo_1 datetime2(7),@__publisherCode_2 nvarchar(4000)',@__p_3=3,@__ef_filter__p_0=0,@__publishedFrom_0='2022-04-22 00:00:00',@__publishedTo_1='2022-07-13 00:00:00',@__publisherCode_2=N'NOM'
```

Furthermore, I find the generated query very strange, because it also contains the sorting, which I need, however, only for the product.

Can anyone tell me how to get all the related entities without applying the other conditions?